# 301 Redirects Library

Tags: http-status-code-301

I am updating my site and there will be new urls for alot of pages.

I now the with IIS7, there is a way to do this with , but is there a library out there that allows adding 301 redirects quickly that works in both IIS6 and IIS7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the ISAPI Rewrite module for IIS, from Iconics. I've had limited luck with it.

http://www.codeplex.com/IIRF

It it were me, I would just handle the BeginRequest event in my global.asax, and manually redirect with 301, depending on some regex rules or maybe even a brute-force dictionary. Of course you would want to find some way to exit early if it didn't match to make sure your site isn't slow.

Comment: If you must use IIS6 then I'd agree with IIRF.  I wrote about my experience with it here: http://swortham.blogspot.com/2008/12/redirecting-default-page-defaultaspx-to.html